# Calling didSelectAnnotationView without a title?

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit

From what I understand the only way to get didSelectAnnotation to be called is if there is a title and canShowCallout is set to true.

I want nothing more than just a pin to show on the map but I need to be able to detect when a pin is tapped. Is there a way to make this work? The other option I guess is to add a tap recognizer to the view, but I need the MKAnnotationView that's being tapped and I'm not quite sure how to access that through a gestureRecognizer.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30858360/adding-a-pin-annotation-to-a-map-view-on-a-long-press-in-swift       this explains about long press on annotation using UILongPressGestureRecognizer .Please try this may be helpful

Comment: You must implement your own MKAnnotationView to deal with long press